# HQL Query starting with REPLACE

Tags: hql, spring-data-jpa

I have a query starting with REPLACE. When I use it directly in `MySQL` console everything is fine, so query is ok. However, when I put it in my code like this:

```
@Query("REPLACE INTO WeekAggregate...
```

There is an error:

```
web - 2016-10-05 10:35:44,297 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter - line 1:1: unexpected token: REPLACE
antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: REPLACE
```

How could I fix this? Is REPLACE not supported in HQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my query to native SQL query by using nativeQuery = true flag.

Answer (score 1):

`HQL` is trasversal to underlying DBMS. So some functions you're using in your SQL can't be interpretated by HQL.

You have two ways:

1. change your HQL query (in this case you can rewrite your query with an DELETE/INSERT statement)
2. you can write your query in SQL and you can use a method createSqlQuery so the interpreter, runs the query as SQL native query.